# Avoiding duplicating line of code by using "or" operator" does not give the same results as when duplicating the line

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement, tuples

I have 3 lists of different words. A word can be in more than 1 lists. I have also a list of sentences. What I did is : I check if a word at a particular index in my sentence is present in one of the above lists of word and If "yes",  then I append the sentence. I used two way.

First way is that:

I write the code for one of the lists of words and I duplicate it but only changing the name of list and the variable where the sentence are append

```
if (pattern_list_tup[pat][2]):
                    if (span[value_of_attribute[pat]] in lexique_1[pattern_list_tup[pat][1]]):
                        if sent not in sentence_extract_lexique_1:
                             sentence_extract_lexique_1.append(sent)                            
                    else:
                        sentence_not_extract_lexique_1.append(sent)

if (pattern_list_tup[pat][2]):
                    if (span[value_of_attribute[pat]] in lexique_2[pattern_list_tup[pat][1]]):
                        if sent not in sentence_extract_lexique_1:
                             sentence_extract_lexique_2.append(sent)                            
                    else:
                        sentence_not_extract_lexique_2.append(sent)

if (pattern_list_tup[pat][2]):
                    if (span[value_of_attribute[pat]] in lexique_3[pattern_list_tup[pat][1]]):
                        if sent not in sentence_extract_lexique_1:
                             sentence_extract_lexique_3.append(sent)                            
                    else:
                        sentence_not_extract_lexique_3.append(sent)
```

As you can see I duplicate the first line  of code and use it for the other lists(lexique). What I did is I decided to print the "union of the three list".

As below:

```
Lists = [sentence_extract_lexique_1, sentence_extract_lexique_2, sentence_extract_lexique_3]
    
    all_union = set.union(*map(set, Lists))
    print("Union des 4 dictionnaires pour phrases extraites", len(all_union), "\n")

# Union des 4 dictionnaires pour phrases extraites  1003
```

Then I come up with another way in order  to not duplicate the first line :  I use the operator "or" as below :

```
 if (pattern_list_tup[pat][2]):
                    if (span[value_of_attribute[pat]] in lexique_1[pattern_list_tup[pat][1]] or lexique_2[pattern_list_tup[pat][1]] or lexique_3[pattern_list_tup[pat][1]] :
                        #print(span[value_of_attribute[pat]])
                        if sent not in sentence:
                            sentence.append(sent)                     
                    else:
                        sentence_not.append(sent)
```

After this line of code I decided to print the result but before printing, I used "set" in order to suppress doublons.

```
print(" phrases totales ", len(sentence))

# phrases totale 1996

sentence = set(sentence)
print("Total après suppression ", len(sentence))

Total après suppression 1556
```

I was wondering why the results are different, using "or "and then deleting doublons should have give the same result as the first way (I believed). Maybe someone can help me figure it out why; I use the second one to present my works but afterwards I re-check the code and to improve , I use "or"; If both answer are not the same, does this means my first solution is false or is the second one the true one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use "or" in this way:

```
if (span[value_of_attribute[pat]] in lexique_1[pattern_list_tup[pat][1]] or lexique_2[pattern_list_tup[pat][1]] or lexique_3[pattern_list_tup[pat][1]] :
```

you either have to do

```
if a in b or a in c....
```

Or you can do

```
for _list in [b, c]:
    if a in _list:
        ....
```

The third way would be to wrap all this code in a function, and call this function using each of the 3 lists.

By the way, doublon is translated as duplicate(s) in English.